# Xcode - how to use localized string from attribute inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, nslocalizedstring

in the attribute inspector i have a placeholder (a.k.a a hint) for a textfield.  The hint is called USERNAME. I'd like to localize this. I have already added the necessary strings into a localizable.strings file.  My question is i would rather reference this string from the inspector itself.  I wish i could do something like localstrings(@"username") right inside the placeholder field itself. I wish i could localize the placeholder string directly from interface builder is what i'm asking for. I've attached an image showing what i'd like to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: Create an IBOutlet, and use `youtTextField.placeholder = "yourString"`

Comment: i wanted to know if there is a way to do it with the interface builder,so i can keep the code more clean.

Comment: If you _really_ like to manage localization in the IB instead of localizing the Storyboard, [this project](https://github.com/nullic/DPLocalizationManager) can help you (it uses IBInspectables that let you provide localized strings for various objects among other things)

Comment: plus one for IBInspectables.  great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localize your storyboard(Main.storyboard), Xcode makes strings file(Main.storyboard) for you, so edit it like...

```
"XXXXXXX.placeholder" = "NOMBRE";
```